# Code structure in Android 2D game

Tags: android, architecture, multithreading

Well I've finnaly decided to start Android game dev, and my first project will be simple 2d canvas based game.
I have some experience in game developing with C# and XNA, and I'm a bit confused now.
Back in XNA we have Game class with Initialize, Update and Draw methods.

In Android I have to extend SurfaceView class, run draw and update in their own thread, and receive touch input from user.

I'm looking for a proper way to structure my code.

Some of my questions are :

- How to deal with Activities (Should I run everything in one activity, or split whole game in 2 or more) ?
- Where should I run game loop ?
- Where to put Draw and Update methods ?
- How to respond to touch events ?

Hope I came to the right place for answers...

Comment: I suggest you want to look at LibGDX. Just like XNA it's a library for games. It has a pretty big community and lots of documentations.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal Breakout game, demonstrating the use of Activities, touch event handling, and draw/update with GLSurfaceView can be found [here](https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout).

Comment: Google Code is being discontinued, and the project has been moved to Github. [Here's the repository](https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout).